# Which gem is good for APNS persistent connection for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, apple-push-notifications

Write now i am using apn_on_rails gem, which is not make persistent connection to APN Servers.
So i want to use gem which will make persistent connection to APN Servers and also will take low memory to server.
I have found following gems for the same

- jnak / apnmachine
- ileitch / rapns
- geoloqi / lead_zeppelin

So please suggest me which one is better.

I really appreciate if someone guide me for the same.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use this one in production https://github.com/nerdsRob/APNS.
It works and it can persist connections with

```
APNS.cache_connections = true
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks roman i will try this one, but is it better than above list which i posted? thanks for replying.

Comment: What's "better" borders on the subjective and will probably get frowned on here